# in Ruby, a binding object would carry a block?

Tags: ruby

```
require 'erb'

temp ="<%= yield %>"

erb = ERB.new(temp)

def get_binding
  binding
end

p erb.result(get_binding{1})  #=> "1"

b = get_binding{1}
p erb.result(b)  #=> "1"

p b.class  #=> Binding

p erb.result(binding{1})  #=> no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError)
```

The get_binding method doesn't take a block and just return a binding object. The block {1} should be lost after the return of get_binding. However when i pass b into the ERB#result, it works like with a block, even though b is just a binding object.

Furthermore, `erb.result(binding{1})` doesn't work, though it should act exactly the same as get_binding. There must be some special distinctions between those two, and i wonder what they are.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question! According to the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-binding), `binding`:

> Returns a `Binding` object, describing the variable and method bindings at the point of call.

Since you are returning a `Binding` object from within a method, that binding can be used to access the variables at the point of the method call. This includes arguments that were passed to the method:

```
def foo(a)
  b = 456
  binding
end

b = foo(123)

b.eval('local_variables') #=> [:a, :b]
b.eval('a')               #=> 123
b.eval('b')               #=> 456
```

and block arguments, too:

```
b = foo(123) { 'block value' }

b.eval('block_given?') #=> true
b.eval('yield')        #=> 'block value'
```

Comment: Good answer. A detail: can one call a block an "argument"?

Comment: @CarySwoveland absolutely: http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument

Comment: i got it. i forgot the block is a part of arguments and can be accessed by yield. thanks again!